# Pip is not installing any libraries

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I have been trying to install numpy using pip on Windows.
But it doesn't seem to be working.

I tried installing numpy and t told me that microsoft C++ package is missing and asked me to install it. I did that and tried re-installing numpy. But this time it doesn't seems to work. It doesn't seem to forward after this point

```
C:\Users\neil>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.9.1.tar.gz
   Running from numpy source directory.
 Installing collected packages: numpy
 Running setup.py install for numpy
```

Then I tried installing scipy, even that doesn't seem to move forward after this point.

```
C:\Users\neil>pip install scipy
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-0.14.1.tar.gz (10.9MB)
   100% |################################| 10.9MB 284kB/s ta 0:00:01
```

Comment: Try using, msi packages. 
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Agreed, definitely use Gohlke's prebuilt binaries. Getting Visual Studio configured correctly to build Python packages is a bloody nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Anaconda. [Anaconda](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install.html#windows-install) is a completely free Python distribution (including for commercial use and redistribution). It includes over 195 of the most popular Python packages for science, math, engineering, data analysis (including numpy and scipy).

After [downloading](http://continuum.io/downloads) the Anaconda installer, double click on the installer application icon and run it.

Follow the instructions in the installer.

The installer is also capable of running in silent mode, without bringing up the graphical interface. To install Anaconda, type the following command into a command prompt:

```
> Anaconda-2.x.x-Windows-x86[_64].exe /S /D=C:\Anaconda
```

Good luck.